# Reading checkbox pdf with python on a filled out form

Tags: python, pdf

I'm having difficulties to read from a filled out form if a box is checked (ticked) or not. I'm currently using PyPDF2 for extracting the text which is working pretty well.

This is my code :

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

infile = "test.pdf"
pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(open(infile, "rb"))

dictionary = pdf_reader.getFormTextFields() # returns a python dictionary
```

If anyone have a hint on this, I'll be very greateful :)

Cheers,
Astrus

Answer (score 1):

PyPDF2 also has a get_fields() command that returns the status of checkboxes. In your example, you'd call it using `pdf_reader.get_fields()`. It will return a dictionary providing the name of the checkbox, the check status ("Yes" if checked, blank if not checked) and some other information. In my experience the name of the checkbox is less than helpful, so figuring out how to connect the checkbox results to the text can be a challenge.

Here's the documentation for get_fields: https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/PdfReader.html#PyPDF2.PdfReader.get_fields

Comment: documentation link is outated, here is the new one [https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/PdfReader.html#PyPDF2.PdfReader.getFields](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/PdfReader.html#PyPDF2.PdfReader.getFields)

Comment: PyPDF2>=2.0.0 has [adjusted its naming patterns](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/user/migration-1-to-2.html#naming-adjustments), so `PdfFileReader` is now `PdfReader` and `getFields` is now `get_fields`.